# Accumulating Gradients

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient-descent

I want to accumulate the gradients before I do a backward pass. So wondering what the right way of doing it is. According to [this article](https://medium.com/huggingface/training-larger-batches-practical-tips-on-1-gpu-multi-gpu-distributed-setups-ec88c3e51255)
it's:

```
model.zero_grad()                                   # Reset gradients tensors
for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(training_set):
    predictions = model(inputs)                     # Forward pass
    loss = loss_function(predictions, labels)       # Compute loss function
    loss = loss / accumulation_steps                # Normalize our loss (if averaged)
    loss.backward()                                 # Backward pass
    if (i+1) % accumulation_steps == 0:             # Wait for several backward steps
        optimizer.step()                            # Now we can do an optimizer step
        model.zero_grad()
```

whereas I expected it to be:

```
model.zero_grad()                                   # Reset gradients tensors
loss = 0
for i, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(training_set):
    predictions = model(inputs)                     # Forward pass
    loss += loss_function(predictions, labels)       # Compute loss function                              
    if (i+1) % accumulation_steps == 0:             # Wait for several backward steps
        loss = loss / accumulation_steps            # Normalize our loss (if averaged)
        loss.backward()                             # Backward pass
        optimizer.step()                            # Now we can do an optimizer step
        model.zero_grad()     
        loss = 0
```

where I accumulate the loss and then divide by the accumulation steps to average it.

Secondary question, if I am right, would you expect my method to be quicker considering I only do the backward pass every accumulation steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So according to the answer [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-gradients-manually-to-zero-in-pytorch/4903/20?u=alband), the first method is memory efficient. The amount of work required is more or less the same in both methods.

The second method keeps accumulating the graph, so would require `accumulation_steps` times more memory. The first method calculates the gradients straight away (and simply adds gradients) so requires less memory.

Answer (score -2):

The backward pass `loss.backward()` is the operation that actually computes the *gradients*.

If you only do the forward pass (`predictions = model(inputs)`) no gradients will be computed and no accumulation is thus possible.

Comment: Hmm I'm already computing the Los in the line after getting the predictions so don't think this answers my question.